# Slow query log of wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'

Tags: mysql

Slow query log:

```
# User@Host: 
# Query_time: 181.648376 Lock_time: 2.114138 Rows_sent: 1425838 Rows_examined: 1663532
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
```

Table has only 650 rows.
Any ideas how can this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible that a query like that `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE column = value`
examines 1663532 rows and sends to the SQL layer 1425838 when the table has only 650 rows. Worst case scenario, it would do a full table scan, examining 650 rows and sending all of them if all of them have `autoload = yes`.

So:

- The query log is incorrect (seems to be truncated, maybe it corresponds to another query?)
- The table had that number of rows at some time in the past, on a different session, or as a temporary table over the real query (it was locked for 2 seconds, so probably there is some write-like activity there).

Please check the result of that select with `EXPLAIN` and with its [handler operations](http://www.slideshare.net/jynus/query-optimization56/15).

Also you can check on the slow log or binary log to detect some ongoing write activity at that time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21318513/1333493 has an alternative explanation